# Опции оптимизации компилятора g++/gcc

Tags: оптимизация, gcc, g++

1. Что значит развертка циклов в контексте обсуждения оптимизации (если можно по рабоче-крестьянски)
2. В некоторых опциях отсутствует встраивание функций...а как без встаивания то? (под встраиванием понял наличие кода функции в экзешнике)
3. Могу ли я компилировать отдельные модули с разными оптимизациями а потом ликновать их в исполняемый файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Развертка цикла - это превращение циклического кода в нециклический. Например, такой код:

   ```
   for(i=0; i<5; i++) func(i);
   ```

   разворачивается в

   ```
   func(0);
   func(1);
   func(2);
   func(3);
   func(4);
   ```

   Развертывание цикла работает, когда количество итераций цикла известно на этапе компиляции. Увеличит размер машинного кода, но может увеличить производительность. Производительность может увеличиться счет отсутствия переходов (если совсем упрощенно - процессору проще выполнять линейный код, плюс линейный код компилятор может дополнительно оптимизировать, специальным образом группируя/переставляя команды).
2. Встраивание ("инлайнинг"), если совсем упрощенно, то это подстановка тела функции в место (вместо) её вызова. Если функция вызывается из нескольких мест, то это увеличит размер машинного кода, но может улучшить производительность, например, если функция вызывается внутри цикла. В зависимости от уровня оптимизации компилятор вполне может встроить функцию не помеченную ключевым словом `inline`. Или не встроить функцию с этим ключевым словом.
3. Можете. Ровно так как вы написали в вопросе - компилируете каждый модуль отдельно, потом линкуете полученные объектные файлы в исполняемый. Особого практического смысла в этом я не вижу.
4. > Перед выбором параметра оптимизации нужно сначала оценить циклы и инлайновые функции кода?

   Оптимизации могут все улучшить, а могут все сломать, особенно если в вашем коде есть части с неопределенным поведением. Плюс на высоком уровне оптимизации могут применяться машинные инструкции, специфичные для вашего процессора, в итоге исполняемый файл может не работать на каких-то компьютерах. Поэтому - пробуйте компилировать на разных уровнях оптимизации, и тестируйте на разных компьютерах. Специально затачивать свой код под особенности какого-то компилятора, или чтобы произошла какая-то оптимизация, ИМХО, не стоит. Лучше делать высокоуровневые оптимизации (оптимизации алгортимов), а низкоуровневые компилятор сам сделает за вас.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А не могли бы уточнить ещё кое что 1) Разворачивание цикла увеличит производительность за счет того что не нужно работать со счётчиком массива (инкремент и проверка условия)?     2) По поводу третьего пунка. Чисто теоретически могу?) Это кто то практикует из адекватных людей?                           3) Компилятор может встроить и не инлайновые функции???     4) Перед выбором параметра оптимизации нужно сначала оценить циклы и инлайновые функции кода?

Comment: @Semerkin, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

> Что значит развертка циклов в контексте обсуждения оптимизации (если можно по рабоче-крестьянски).

Допустим есть три вектора и цикл:

```
int a[3], b[3] , c[3];
// ...
for (int i =0; i<3; ++i) {
  c[i] = a[i] +b[i];
}
```

Развёртка циклов значит, что компилятор может заменить этот цикл на ассемблерный код аналогичный сгенерированному из следующего:

```
c[0] = a[0] + b[0];
c[1] = a[1] + b[1];
c[2] = a[2] + b[2];
```

> В некоторых опциях отсутствует встраивание функций...а как без встаивания то? (под встраиванием понял наличие кода функции в экзешнике)

Не правильно, встраивание функций это то о чём даёт подсказку ключевое слово `inline`. Т.е. в случае:

```
inline int add (int a, int b) { return a+b;}

int main (void) {
  int aMain,bMain;
  // ... 
  int c = add (aMain, bMain);
}
```

Тело **может быть** подставлено в место своего вызова. Т.е. код по факту может получиться аналогично следующему:

```
int main (void) {
  int aMain,bMain;
  // ... 
  int c = aMain + bMain;
}
```

Важный момент: решение о встраивании принимает всегда компилятор, inline — лишь «советует» ему и подстраивает его эвристики.

> Могу ли я компилировать отдельные модули с разными оптимизациями а потом ликновать их в исполняемый файл?

Вообще говоря — да, по крайней мере для флагов из `-O[123s]` это не должно создавать проблем. Но ИМХО можно подобрать некоторые комбинации флагов, которые будут вызывать конфликты или ошибки (например различные `-fabi-version=*`).

Comment: Спасибо! А Вы часто оптимизации используете на практике? лет 6 назад на стеке уже задавали похожий вопрос и там было отмечено что использование оптимизаций может привести к краху программы, причем во время исполнения спустя какое то время...

Comment: @Semerkin, Оптимизации для боевого кода почти всегда обязательны. Низкие уровни оптимизации, условно говоря, (-O1 и -O2) можно использовать практически всегда. Изменение поведения на  них свидетельствует об ошибке в программе и вероятнее всего вызваны UB, так что если придерживаться стандарта, то они фактически безопасны. `-Ofast` напротив добавляет опасные оптимизации, изменяющие поведение, при его применении обязательно прочитать про все флаги им добавляемые и желательно писать тесты. `-O3` — почти всегда также безопасен, как и -O[12] но может, например, обострить состояние гонки.

Comment: Спасибо! А разве можно обострить состояние гонки (честно впервые вижу что это обостряется)? Состояние гонки оно либо есть либо нет.

Comment: @Semerkin условно говоря.... на -O2 ошибка может возникать один раз из 1000, а на -O3 один из 10. Понятно, что это эфимерная и вероятностная вещь и вполне может случиться обратное...

Comment: Ого! так тогда всякие эти оптимизации лишают программиста всякого понимания что делает его код! Гонка за ресурсами это серьёзно...получается каждый .экзе лучше гонять со всякими отладчиками - полагаю это избавит от проблем

Comment: @Semerkin мм.... сарказм?

Comment: @Semerkin, лучший способ разобраться во всем этом -- чтение ассемблерного кода, который делает компилятор, если задать ему флаг `-S`. Кстати, наиболее "человеческий" код обычно получается при уровне оптимизации `-s`

Comment: @avp `-s` - не оптимизация (в смысле ускорения кода), а просто удаление некоторой информации, которая может пригодиться при дебаге. Т.е. это оптимизация (уменьшение) размера бинарника.

Comment: @zed, `-s` (точнее, конечно же `-Os`) это именно оптимизация с целью получения компактного кода, а не просто удаление некоторой информации. Впрочем, просто сами сравните тексты, получаемые без оптимизации, с -O2 и c -Os (два последних будут значительно более похожи друг на друга, чем любой из них на первый (тот, что вообще без оптимизации))

Comment: @avp `-Os` и `-s` это совершенно разные вещи и не надо их смешивать. `-Os` - применение оптимизаций *генерирования кода* уровня `-O2`, которые не приводят к увеличению размеров кода + некоторые оптимизация для уменьшения размеров кода. А вот `-s` - это удаление некоторой метаинформации. Код она не трогает. Код сгенерированный с опциями `-Os` и `-O3` скорее всего будет отличаться по скорости (`-O3` более быстрый), но наличие/отсутствие флага `-s` в обоих случаях на скорость никак влиять не должно.

Comment: @zed, очевидно же, что говоря об оптимизации я имел в виду именно `-Os` (описочка в комменте вышла -)) (кстати, вы уверены, что `-s` это флаг *компилятора* (а не линкера)?)